# Does the following constitute defamation?

Tags: united-states, defamation

There are two candidates running for public office in a small midwestern city. Both of them are public figures, within the context of the defamation laws. Candidate A is running on a "morality" platform, cut funding for birth control and abortion, teach children abstinence in schools, etc.

He accuses candidate B of being "soft' on moral issues, and cites prevailing rumors/reports that candidate B's *daughter* was impregnated out of wedlock, and had an abortion. The truth is that the daughter is dating a man whose *previous* girlfriend "was impregnated out of wedlock, and had an abortion" by the man.

Is this grounds for a lawsuit? I can think of two reasons why this might be true. First the daughter might not be a public figure, and therefore would "normal" standards of defamation apply to her?Second, even if a suit by her were held to the higher public figure standard, might she be able to prove "malice or reckless disregard for the truth"?

Answer (score 2):

No.  In the United States, it's easy to argue that the daughter, as a candidate's child, is a public figure, especially if she had appeared in any capacity on her father's campaign or spoke about her father in a political manner.  This is the proverbial "Entering the Arena" that could hold her to public commentary.   A good question as to whether or not she counts as a public figure is asking "But for the public remarks made by Candidate A, would the the daughter be unknown from the public or out of the media spotlight?  Usually it would be a "N".   As a general unwritten rule of campaigns children are off limits, but it's not a crime to disparage a politicians kids... just a public outrage.

Furthermore, in your second paragraph, Candidate A  is citing prevailing rumors/reports that this did happen, so Mr. A did not make this up on his own, but repeated something from some other source.  Since the rumor is already out there, it's something of public concern, which is not defamation.   Candidate A could further mitigate the suit if he promptly apologized upon learning of the screw up and corrected the record.  Either way, since he was speaking on a publicly available source (even if incorrect) his repeating of incorrect facts that at the time he believed were factual and relevent to the campaign.

In one particular way to get around defimation is to couch the terms in notions of other people's words.  It is defamatory to say she had an abortion (a lie, she did not, and is injurious to her character) and a completely different thing to say "I have heard rumors that she had an abortion" (which is true).  Whether or not "She had an abortion" is factual or false, it is factual that there are rumors, and it is factual that he has heard some rumors.  He's not commenting on the verasity of the rumors, but the mere fact that the rumors exist and he is aware of them... but perfectly self-demonstrating:  He just demonstrated the rumor's nature, thus proving the rumor exists, and he has heard about it (If it was started by connecting it to dirty politics, daughter has to prove that).  Incidentally, this is why when we arrest someone who committed a mass murder spree that was captured on numerous security cameras and news footage, the news will refer to the individual as the "Accused Mass Murder First Second Third-Name" and not "Mass Murder First Second Third-Name", because under the eyes of the law, he's not-guilty until he pleas his guilt or is found guilty by the jury.  If the News reports that he did it before a trial, (even if we watch the whole thing unfold on national tv) they can be sued by the accused because it's not yet true that he was guilty of mass murder.

Comment: "*it's not a crime to disparage a politicians kids*". That is inaccurate in the case of falsely imputed crimes. For instance, see [MCL 750.370](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/(S(ngxrxjy4asm4nhnzfzrejnz5))/mileg.aspx?page=getObject&objectName=mcl-750-370). That type of falsehoods is classified as misdemeanor, hence a crime, and it makes no exception. Thus, it also applies even if the defamed person is a politician's child. The lack of enforcement of such legislation is another story, and that does not change the actual and current legislation.

Comment: @IñakiViggers:  Not remotely what disparage means (generally means mean spirited opinionated statements about a person).  My opinions are never considered factual statements, and again, cannot be defamatory.

Comment: Wrong on the "especially if" part about relatives being a public figure: it's *only* if.

Comment: "*Not remotely what disparage means*". The OP's scenario makes clear reference to pregnancy out of wedlock and abortion. The former means an attribution of want of chastity, whereas the latter still is a crime in many (perhaps all?) jurisdictions in the U.S. Thus, while your remark about statements of opinion is correct at law, it is irrelevant to the OP's question.

Comment: @IñakiViggers:  No jurisdiction beyond US where Abortion is legal in all but one state and even then, the changes in the law haven't gone in to effect.  And again, The politician disagrees with Abortion, he has read bad reports that have not yet been corrected in any official records, and the guy is entitled to believe that her having an out of wedlock pregnacy terminated by an abortion is fundimentally bad.  There are people who disagree with that of course, but there's no evidence that he continued the attack after the record was corrected.  Personal opinion does in fact matter here.

Comment: @Nij I should have qualified my remark. I had in mind the abortion which is illegal and which keeps much the recurrent debate about *Roe v. Wade* alive.

Comment: @IñakiViggers:  could you clean up that last statement?  Not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: "*the guy is entitled to believe that [...]*". Anyone is entitled believe anything no matter how unreasonable a belief might be, but that is not the point. When it comes to defamation law, a defamer's belief would have to be *reasonable*. Otherwise, the defamer will have a hard time disproving that he uttered falsehoods with *actual malice*. As for cleaning the last statement, I was just conceding what Nij pointed out that abortion is legal, and thus clarified that I had in mind the legal, current limitations on abortion.

Comment: @IñakiViggers:  Canidate A is not a defamer per OP's scenario.  The case has yet to go to trial.  He is an **accused defamer** .  And because of that mistake, you could now be sued by Mr. A for defamation of his own character, since at the moment, he is legally innocent of the crime.   Had you merely used one additional word, you would have been safe, because at the time of speaking him, it is true, he is accused.  But because you didn't you defamed him, because again, legally, at time of writing, he is not guilty of the crime.

Comment: " If the News reports that he did it before a trial, (even if we watch the whole thing unfold on national tv) they can be sued by the accused because it's not yet true that he was guilty of mass murder." That's nonsense. A person either committed the act or not. A conviction means that they are now *found* not guilty; before the conviction, they hadn't been *found* guilty, but that doesn't mean that they were not guilty. This person could *sue*, but to *win*, they would have to convince the jury that they didn't, and "I haven't been convicted yet" would not suffice.

Comment: @Acccumulation:  Then why will the News call him an "Accused" murder, and not a "Murder"?

Comment: I thought that if you repeat a rumor, you are as liable as if you made up the rumor. "A false statement is not less libelous because it is the repetition of rumor or gossip or of statements or allegations that others have made concerning the matter." -- Ray v. Citizen-News Co.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz:  Keep in mind it was reported on as well, so it's not so much rumor or rumor not acknoledge by press.   If at the time of the Politicians Statements, the Daughter had not come forward with the truth, than he hasn't "KNOWINGLY" made false statements.  If he earnestly believed at the time the statements were truthful.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I believe that what you said is true under British law. I don't think it applies to American law.

Answer (score -1):

> Is this grounds for a lawsuit?

Yes.

> would "normal" standards of defamation apply to her?

Yes. Unfortunately those "normal" standards imply that, in order to recover more than $1 for *nominal damages*, the daughter will have to prove that the falsehoods were made with *actual malice* (that is, with reckless disregard for the truth or despite knowing these were false) even if she is not a public figure.

Under pretext of protecting [defamer's] First Amendment rights, the defamer will not even be compelled to publicly retract his falsehoods even if these are disproved and patently false. That is the screwed state of affairs of U.S. defamation law.

> even if a suit by her were held to the higher public figure standard, might she be able to prove "malice or reckless disregard for the truth"?

Yes. Candidate A's knowledge about the boyfriend's *previous* girlfriend reflects the great extent to which he must have investigated candidate B's situation & environment. That extent of scrutiny would be inconsistent with candidate A's subsequent denial --in court-- that he acted with *actual malice* at the time of deliberately publishing his falsehoods.

In denying the defamer's actual malice, it would be quite a stretch to pretend that the defamer (1) got confused between "daughter" and "daughter's boyfriend's previous girlfriend" (2) when making statements on a topic of great relevance for someone whose own campaign centers on a "morality" platform.

Comment: The candidate got the wrong person so he obviously does not know the statement is false.

Comment: @Putvi In contexts such as election campaigns, it is naive to buy the theory that the "*opponent's daughter*" was confused with the "*opponent's daughter's boyfriend's previous girlfriend*". The latter is too convoluted and too distant to be "innocently" confused with someone so directly related to the opponent in an election.

Comment: You may be right, but if you had to prove it you could not.

Comment: As I pointed out in my own answer, the politician cites rumors/reports, so he's not the source of the false info, he's just using it on an attack.   He's aloud to bring it up as the rumor/report was in the public sphere before he made the comments and at the time, the correction had not been made.

Comment: @hszmv You would be right only if the candidate's emphasis is on the *existence* of those rumors. But when the emphasis is on the falsehoods themselves and/or the intent is such (as is likely the case in a context of politics and election campaigns), it will not help the defamer to prefix his falsehoods with "*there are rumors that [...]*", nor will it be relevant for the defamer to allege that he is not "the source of the false info".

Comment: @IñakiViggers Rumors and REPORTS... as in, some sort of press has been made on the matter and referencing that is pefrecty fine.  After all, it is factually true that Rumors and Reports of the matter... not that the matter is true or false.   It's like saying "The Accused Murder" in a news report about someone who is facing trial for Murder that pretty much was captured on live TV... he hasn't been tried yet so legally speaking, he is still innocent.

Comment: @hszmv The OP did not make it clear what exactly the hypothetical defamer said nor how he cited the "rumors and reports". Hence, one cannot rule out that framing it as "rumors and reports" carries a defamatory purpose and/or emphasis on the falsehoods. You are assuming that the defamer centered on the mere *existence* of rumors and reports, but that is not clear --let alone unequivocal-- in the OP's question.

Comment: @IñakiViggers:  You mean my proffessors shouldn't have failed me for not backing up my term papers by citing my sources because they could be false?   The whole point of citing your sources is to show where you justified that statement.   And if he's citing reports, it's in the news and thus, he is commenting on public interests.

Comment: @hszmv I don't know why your professors failed you (nor even that they failed you), but that is irrelevant to defamation and to the OP's question. My point, again, is that prefixing a statement with language such as "*there are reports that [...]*" does not necessarily or automatically preempt liability under U.S. defamation law. Also, the position that a kid's sexual life pertains to public interest simply because "*it's in the news*" sounds morbid and it misleads those of the audience who are not knowledgeable of defamation law.

Comment: @IñakiViggers:  Are you from the United States, because those are actually things in the United States?  The Defamation laws here are very in the favor of the person who made the statement in question (As are most speech laws that we have, our jurisprudence demands the accuser must prove the statements made were not protected.).

Comment: I have extensively litigated defamation in the U.S. In particular, [*Milkovich v. Lorain Journal Co.*, 497 U.S. 1, 18-19 (1990)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/indcco20161222066) is one of various precedents dismantling your mistaken presumption that "opinion prefixes" (and, impliedly, "citing rumors and reports") preempt liability for defamation.
Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93946/discussion-between-inaki-viggers-and-hszmv).